# User object (req.user) structure doesn't match the database model schema after authentication with Passport.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js

I have an Express.js application developed in JavaScript. I've recently learned TypeScript and I'm migrating the project from JS to TS.

I use Prisma as my ORM.

Somewhere in my app, there's a route for user login and I use Passport.js for authentication.
Here's the main part of passport-local strategy code I use:

```js
let strategy = new LocalStrategy(
  { usernameField: "tel" },
  async (tel, pass, cb) => {
    let encryptedTel = encrypt(tel) as string;
    let user = await prisma.users.findUnique({
      where: {
        tel: encryptedTel,
      }
    });

    if (!user) {
      return cb(new UnauthorizedErr('شماره همراه یا رمز ورود اشتباه است.'));
    }

    let isPassMatch = await compare(pass, user.password);

    if (isPassMatch) {
      cb(null, user); // the structure of `user` here is correct
    }
    else {
      cb(new UnauthorizedErr('شماره همراه یا رمز ورود اشتباه است.'));
    }
  }
);

export default strategy;
```

After the user is successfully authenticated, I call the `cb` with the user object retrieved from database. The user object has the same structure as the `users` model in my `prisma.schema`.

The problem is: in the middleware after passport authentication, the user object populated in `req.user` doesn't have the same schema as the db model. Here's the middleware code:

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { sign } from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { decrypt } from '../../helpers/cipherFunc';
import { unescape } from '../../helpers/sanitizeInputs';
import { users } from '@prisma/client';
import passport from 'passport';
import inputValidator from '../../validation/inputValidators/loginInputs';
import storeValidatedInputs from '../../middlewares/storeValidatedInputs';

const controller = [
  storeValidatedInputs(inputValidator),

  // authenticate user
  passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }),

  // authentication successful
  (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    let token = sign(
      { id: req.user.id, tel: req.user.tel },
      process.env.JWT_TOKEN_SECRET as string,
      { expiresIn: '90d' }
    );

    // decrypt user object values
    let decryptedUser = {
      id: req.user.id,
      full_name: unescape(req.user.full_name),
      tel: decrypt(req.user.tel),
      email: decrypt(req.user.email),
      birthday: req.user.birthday,
      credit_card_num: decrypt(req.user.credit_card_num),
      national_id: decrypt(req.user.national_id),
      profile_pic_url: req.user.profile_pic_url,
    };

    res.json({
      token,
      user: decryptedUser,
    });
  },
];

export default controller;
```

All the `req.user`s in the code have this error:
[image: req.user error]

I can fix this error with something like this (although I don't know if it's a right way to do it):

```js
req.user = req.user as users; // users is the user schema in database imported from @prisma/client
```

All the properties of `req.user` in the code have an error like this:
[image: req.user properties errors]

`req.user` has the structure of `Express.User` interface defined in the passport type definitions.  This interface is empty: `namespace Express { interface User {} }`. I think this is the reason I can't access no properties on `req.user`. How do I fix this?

Shouldn't `req.user` have the same data structure as the `user` object retrieved from database in passport-local strategy?

I tried to fix the problems with type assertions, but it didn't work.